# Android- Content of forms not adjusting when keyboard opens

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-fragments, view

I have a form which has few edit text and below all there is button like this
[This is a form on fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5Zds.jpg)
Its looks fine until i open keyboard the form doesn't resize itself even after applying different property like

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN |WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE );
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE );
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE |WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE );
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE |WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN );
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_MODE_CHANGED);
```

Also i tried in manifest and in fragment layout but most of it i can achieve this 
[The buttons Comes Up Not EditText](https://i.stack.imgur.com/721W2.jpg)

Here is my Fragment Layout where is EditTexts

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"

    >

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_below="@+id/Uploader"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/view4"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/first_Name"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_black_24dp"

        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:hint="First Name"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/last_Name" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="185dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/view"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/view"
        android:id="@+id/view2">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="175dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_perm_identity_black_24dp"
        android:id="@+id/last_Name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:hint="Last Name" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view2"
        android:id="@+id/view3">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:hint="Enter Phone Number"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp"
       />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/view4">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/mailID"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Enter Email Address"
         />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view2"
        android:id="@+id/view6">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_lock_black_24dp"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"
        android:hint="Enter Password"


        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:id="@+id/Submit"
        android:text="SUBMIT"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="74dp" />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_add_a_photo_black_48dp"
        android:id="@+id/Uploader"


        android:layout_marginTop="84dp"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/Image_Preview"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/Uploader"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/Uploader"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Uploader" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/regUser"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/view3" />



</RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

My layout is not adjusting even after trying `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` in layout file and also in manifest

Comment: What do you want the layout to look like?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Can you check both images you would know what i want to achieve and in second image in link u can see only submit button is going above keyboard not whole form so i want all edit text and button should go above when keyboard is open

Comment: Do you want the view to scroll up so that you see more of the edit texts? Or do you want the layout to fit all of the edit texts in the available area when the keyboard is onscreen?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice   scroll up so i can see alll edit text boxs whn i scroll screen i dont want my edit text to shrink in available layout after keyboard is open

Comment: To start, you need to add a `ScrollView` to your layout so that it can scroll.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice even after ScrollVIew my Buttons comes over last edittext as in image i shown above submit button just above keyboard.Please check edited layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Submit" button has `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` which is what makes it appear just above the keyboard. You need to change this to an appropriate `layout_*` param which places it where you actually want it. In fact, you should consider using a `LinearLayout` or `TableLayout` in order to keep the child views where you want them.

Comment: Thanks its works and i set marginTop=425dp to align below of the last edit text

Comment: @KabirRaz It would probably be better to use `android:layout_below` rather than such a large margin. This will be more portable across different device sizes.

Comment: when i use any layout property in above layout file `android:layout_below="@+id/password"` its shows @+id/password is not a sibling in the same relativelayout so i have to use margin

Comment: @KabirRaz The password EditText is contained in a `TextInputLayout`. If you give this `TextInputLayout` an id, you can use that for `layout_below`.